# side by side Inline-block divs, last one aligned in the middle wrongly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm aligning responsive divs side by side vertically in pairs. I'm using inline-block instead of floats. I cannot use flex btw.
In the example below I have 5 divs, but the last one (div5) goes in the middle instead of aligning to the left. I cannot understand why.

Any suggestion?

What happening is:

```
div1  div2
div3  div4  
   div5   

instead of:

div1 div2
div3 div4
div5
```

The CSS and HTML:

```css
div-container{
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 95%;
}
    
div{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 48%;
  margin-right: 4%;
  margin-bottom: 4%;
}
    
div:nth-child(2n+2) {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="div-container"><div>
     <div class="image-box">
       <a href="#" title="tile">
                        <img class="img-teaser" src="./img/partner1.png" alt="Partner 1 image">
                      </a>
                    </div>
    
                    <div class="content-box">
                      <div class="text-box">
                          <a href="#" title="card">
                            <h3>Hea</h3>
                          </a>
                          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque ultricies non nisi id pellentesque. </p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
    
     <div>
                   <div class="image-box">
                      <a href="#" title="tile">
                        <img class="img-teaser" src="./img/partner1.png" alt="Partner 1 image">
                      </a>
                    </div>
    
                    <div class="content-box">
                      <div class="text-box">
                          <a href="#" title="card">
                            <h3>Hea</h3>
                          </a>
                          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque ultricies non nisi id pellentesque. </p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
    
     <div>
                   <div class="image-box">
                      <a href="#" title="tile">
                        <img class="img-teaser" src="./img/partner1.png" alt="Partner 1 image">
                      </a>
                    </div>
    
                    <div class="content-box">
                      <div class="text-box">
                          <a href="#" title="card">
                            <h3>Hea</h3>
                          </a>
                          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque ultricies non nisi id pellentesque. </p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
    
     <div>
     <div class="image-box">
                      <a href="#" title="tile">
                        <img class="img-teaser" src="./img/partner1.png" alt="Partner 1 image">
                      </a>
                    </div>
    
                    <div class="content-box">
                      <div class="text-box">
                          <a href="#" title="card">
                            <h3>Hea</h3>
                          </a>
                          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque ultricies non nisi id pellentesque. </p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
    
     <div>
                    <div class="image-box">
                      <a href="#" title="tile">
                        <img class="img-teaser" src="./img/partner1.png" alt="Partner 1 image">
                      </a>
                    </div>
    
                    <div class="content-box">
                      <div class="text-box">
                          <a href="#" title="card">
                            <h3>Hea</h3>
                          </a>
                          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque ultricies non nisi id pellentesque. </p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please can you include full code (HTML and CSS) to enable us to reproduce your problem. Best guess at the moment is `text-align: center;` set on a parent element.

Comment: Sorry, I've just attached the HTML.

Comment: @HiddenHobbes maybe you meant text-align: left on the parent?

Comment: @JishnuVS yes I've checked that and it works but the alignment should be left to obtain what I need.

Comment: @Beppe , sorry  i misunderstand the question, i thought you want the last box to be centerd

Comment: @JishnuVS not a problem at all, your example still pretty useful for future reference.

Comment: @Beppe, I meant what was causing your issue was `text-align: center;`. Just for future reference please ensure that your code allows us to reproduce the issue, with your amendments the issue you describe is still not visible (the blocks are aligned to the left). A Stack Snippet is a good way to demonstrate the issue and will reduce potential confusion.

Comment: @HiddenHobbes sure will do, thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `text-align: left;` to `div-container`

Answer (score 2):

Try with this snippet,  add `text-align:center` to the parent div , this will make the last div to be left

```css
.all-box {
 width:400px;
 margin:0 auto;
 text-align:left;
}
.box {
 width:49%;
 display:inline-block;
 height:100px;
 background:#666;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="all-box">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The question here is to align the last div to the left, and not centre. Please edit your answer accordingly.

Comment: @nashcheez yes i have misunderstand the question, now its fine

Answer (score 1):

Try removing

```
margin-right: 4%;
margin-bottom: 4%;
```

for div tag

Comment: Hey, no effect if I remove them.